# 4th order low pass Butterworth filter with very low Q factor

Tags: low-pass, active-filter, bode-plot, frequency-response

I have designed a 4th order low-pass Butterworth filter with a 0.707 Q factor. However, what I am getting is almost no flatness in the pass band region and my frequency response looks like a half of a projectile motion graph. What is causing this? Is my Q factor actually way lower than 0.707?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show details... define "very low"

Comment: Kale? Come on. Do you imagine we read minds or that we have working crystal balls?? Please help and provide us with something to work with here! For example... your design? I think getting reasoned answers has a much better chance if you'd share with us. Otherwise, how do you imagine anyone can help you?

Comment: For Butterworth(4), the pair of 2nd order characteristic equations are:
$$
s^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}} +\left( 2+\sqrt{2}\right)^\frac32}{4}s + 1
\\
s^2 + \frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} + \left( 2-\sqrt{2}\right)^\frac32}{4}s + 1
$$or$$s^4 + 2.613126s^3 + 3.4142136s^2 + 2.613126s + 1$$Now let's see how you applied this.

Comment: Finally, if you want a flavor of what it is like tweaking filters of still higher order, see [this](https://nuwaves.com/using-time-to-save-time-tuning-filters/)! When I had to develop a 6-pole transmit filter and a 10-pole receive filter for a 600 bps FSK modem, I had this kind of trouble in my life. It was NOT fun. I decided I'd never do it again as a hobby effort. One time is enough for a lifetime. Just FYI.

Comment: A 4th-oder filter has no "Q factor". The Q- factor is defined for a pole pair only - hence, for a 2nd-order filter stage only. A 4th-order filter has two (normally different) Q-factors - resulting in the desired transfer function. For a 4th-order Butterworth function we have Q1=0.5412 and Q2=1.3065.

Answer (score 1):

For a 4th order Butterworth LPF, you have each stage with a Q of 0.54 and 1.31 at f-3dB for the resulting filter. However, if you do not have a GWB >= 100 * f0 * Av for the Op Amps then the gain phase response will not be maximally flat.

For example here with GBW = 1MHz, 4th Order Butterworth at 0.1 MHz, Av=1.0 there is a gain error 4.4dB at 0.1 MHz.  The cardinal rule for Av*BW=GBW only applies to the internal integrator which is a 1st order LPF near 10 Hz.

As Q increases >10  this GBW requirement tends towards towards Q^2 * Av* fo

[image]